# Sigsegv error, whats wrong?

Tags: c

I'm trying to cope with my exercise. I have to input n (up to 10^6) integers separated by space in single line and sum them.
For e.g. 0 1 541 10 54 100000000...

I tried scanf, but it takes to much time (Limit for this algorithm is only 1sec):

```
int n;
long long int sum;
scanf("%d\n", &n);
          while(n--){
               scanf(" %d", &value);
               suma+= value;
          }
```

I decided to read that line as char array, and then split using space as delimiter.

```
int n;
long long int sum;
scanf("%d\n", &n);
char tab[n];
scanf("%[^\n]s", tab);
char* split=strtok(tab," ");

    while(split != NULL){
         suma += atoi(split);
         split=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
```

But it doesn't work :/ Probably there is a problem with bounds of array, but I'm not sure and I can't repair this error.

Comment: What input are you giving it to make it crash? And what is `suma`?

Comment: check `n > 0` before doing `char tab[n];` and you have no protection against the following scanf doing a buffer overflow.  If you entered `0` or `1` for `n` that would explain your problems.

Comment: What is that first number `n` scanned as the first? You are *using* it as the total string length.

Comment: Do you know how big 10^6 is?

Comment: N is a number of elements in sequence. So if N=5 in the second line I should write 5 numbers separated by space. Security is not needed. I'm sure that input is correct without letters.

Answer (score 0):

Fix last call to strtok() to receive argument ++split instad of NULL

Comment: Thats don't work. When i changed split=strtok(NULL," "); to
split=strtok(++split," "); program stoped after first loop